# Visual Studio 2022 automatically changes indenting even though adaptive formatting is turned off

Tags: visual-studio-2022

VS 2022 has an extremely irritating habit of moving my code after I indent them to my satisfaction.  In one case, I found that turning off adaptive formatting helped.  However, I just found a case where it didn't.

I like to line up function arguments under the opening parenthesis of the function call.  I have this little block of code:

```
std::unique_ptr<CPVStaticTextCollapsibleWnd>    spStaticTextCollapsible(
    new CPVStaticTextCollapsibleWnd(this,
                                    IDB_EXPANDED_NODE,
                                    IDB_COLLAPSED_NODE,
                                    m_spRowCollection));
```

After I click the Save button, it looks like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<CPVStaticTextCollapsibleWnd>    spStaticTextCollapsible(
    new CPVStaticTextCollapsibleWnd(this,
        IDB_EXPANDED_NODE,
        IDB_COLLAPSED_NODE,
        m_spRowCollection));
```

How can I tell VS 2022 to leave my indenting alone?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your Save Profile under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Code Cleanup.
Disable/remove "Document formatting".